# DNSCrypt: How to prevent Windows from resolving blacklisted names?

Tags: windows, networking, dns, opendns

I set up DNSCrypt in Windows 10 and **disabled** the **DNS Client** service, which caches and resolves DNS. Then, for testing purpose, I put `*google*` in the DNSCrypt **block list** and tried to resolve the name. Indeed it blocks:

[image]

However, when I try to navigate to google.com in the browser it opens the website (although it takes longer to resolve the name)

So why the name was resolved and who resolved it? Is there a way to avoid these DNS "trespassing"?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### I found the problem and the solution.

Turns out, when you **change** the DNS IP in the NIC, Windows will not discard that DNS IP. It will keep that DNS IP in a "hidden" list. Later, it will use those DNS you have removed. Tricky and nasty Windows.
Just click in 'advanced' and then you can see Windows kept all the old DNS IPs you once have used.

[image]

I removed all those IPs and set only `127.0.0.1`. **Problem solved**.

---

Note that Mozilla Firefox 60 may use its own DNS to resolve addresses.

**Update:** to remove all prior DNS server IPs from the command line:

`netsh interface ipv4 delete dnsserver "Ethernet" all`