# DNS redirect to localhost

Tags: windows, dns, ipv6, localhost, nslookup

Is it normal ?

I configured in Windows settings the IPv4 DNS of OpenDNS and the nslookup in CMD return for a domain [::1] or 127.0.0.1 from fe80::a63e:51ff:fe58:9ddd

I tried the same on WSL and and it is the IPv4 OpenDNS who reply me normally with the good destination IP

Comment: Show us exactly what you are doing. Use screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same problem in the past and it took me some time to figure it out.
The problem is Windows **keeps** DNS resolvers that you used in the past and will keep using them, until you remove them from this hidden list in **Advanced DNS settings**.

[image]

Make sure you remove the DNS entries you don't want to use for both **IPv4 and IPv6**  otherwise windows will still use them. Keep only the DNS hosts you willing to use.

Comment: Check this: https://superuser.com/questions/1349445/